# Rails 7 with importmap and Stimulus not working on IOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, stimulusjs, import-maps

I'm facing a situation that I'm stuck for some time now.

I have an application that I recently updagraded from Rails 6 to Rails 7. Now I want to use Stimulus to replace some VueJS that I have.

What I did:

1. Installed Stimulus and ImportMap
2. Refactored my VueJS to Stimulus
3. Gotrid of Webpacker (that I was using only for VueJS)

I was able to do all this, but stimulus doesn't run on IOS . Any other place I tested, it's working fine.

(I have a feeling that my asset pipeline and webpacker are messy, because I have different `application.js` files on `app/assets/javascript`, `app/javascript` and `app/javascript/packs`)